# Making certain apps open everytime at certain places?

Tags: launcher

I want to make certain apps always open at certain position (for example sticked to the left edge of the second monitor) and at certain desktop or visible on all desktops.

Is there an easy way to automate this?

Comment: You need to tell people what your operating system is and which window manager you are using.

Comment: it's ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's **devilspie** (or the GUI version, **gdevilspie**). Both versions are installable from the Software Center and allow you to define rules altering (amongst other things) the size and position of  matching windows. The [community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie) can get you started on using them.

If you are using Unity (and thus Compiz), there's the [Window Matching plugin](http://wiki.compiz.org/WindowMatching), which essentially does the same thing. In order to access it, install the package **compizconfig-settings-manager** and start the CCSM. If you can't find the Window Matching plugin, make sure that **compiz-plugins** is installed.